# No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/ in Spring generated by codegen with swagger

Tags: spring, swagger, codegen

I am learning swagger using the example pet store in the swagger editor: https://editor.swagger.io/

The code for spring is generated and I does not change anything. However, everytime I run it on http://localhost:8080, it gives the error message

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/
HTTP ERROR 404
```

But I believe I am supposed to see something like in the following website:
https://petstore.swagger.io/
May I ask how to solve this issue? Many thanks.

I follow the URL in the controller class HomeController.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("swagger-ui.html");
        return "redirect:swagger-ui.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the context path is v2.

You should be able to access the demo at:
`http://localhost:8080/v2/<endoint>`

Try accessing:
http://localhost:8080/v2/swagger-ui.html

The context path is defined in a configuration file titled `application.properties` located under `src/main/resource`. The file contains the following:

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs
server.contextPath=/v2
server.port=8080
spring.jackson.date-format=io.swagger.RFC3339DateFormat
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

The context path is defined under `server.contextPath`.

Comment: I can now open. But why? How do you know this?

Comment: There's a spring configuration file called `application.properties` that defines the base URL (technically called the contextPath), under src/main/resource.  I updated my answer with the content of the file.  Let me know if you have issue locating the file in your own environment.

Answer (score 2):

You might be visiting the wrong URL. Try out `http://localhost:8080/<base-url>/swagger-ui.html`

Additionally, you could refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) for a basic setup.

Comment: What is the base url

Comment: But in readMe file: You can view the api documentation in swagger-ui by pointing to
http://localhost:8080/

Comment: May I know In which framework are you trying to build your server? Base url is the piece of the URI which you set in your application which is a common string after your hostname, in your case `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: In your case the '/' url is directly redirected to 'swagger-ui.html'. Hence you can just use `http://localhost:8080/v2/`